# Need a recommendation on a software to make a website connected to a database

Tags: web-development, php, wordpress

So I am adding a webpage to an already existing website that would take information hopefully through a form and have a pin on a map that points them to it. Should I use wordpress or making a PHP(a language that I know) file.

Comment: Is security a major concern?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Google Maps API with your PHP experience. The Google Maps API is well documented and will easier than most other options out there, since Google hosts the map part.

Essentially, you can embed the Maps widget in any webpage then write JavaScript to get the form info you need and customize the map. It sould be easy for a PHP developer to understand JS.

You could also use a PHP Google Maps SDK to make things work. Here's one on GitHuib that could work: https://github.com/biscolab/google-maps-php-sdk. You'll have to see what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no expierence with web development, it's maybe a good idea to start with a (auto updating) CMS/Framework like wordpress because of security reasons. The GUI helps you to get fast results.

If you want to dig into web development or if you are expierenced, it would produce less overhead to program your (simple) tasks directly with PHP or another language.

Comment: Remember that this is an existing site, presumably working. Should the OP convert the whole existing site to a framework? Also, you say "`If you have no experience with web development,`", where the OP states "`HP(a language that I know)`"

Comment: Security and Wordpress generally don't go together.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use PHP as the P part of a LAMP stack.

However, for the sake of your personal sanity I recommend using a framework like laravel which does some of the backend work for you.  It definitely adds a bunch of security without forcing you to learn how to do secure prepare SQL queries.

There are dozens of frameworks to choose from.

Just make sure you choose one that is still actively being developed.  That way when issues are found the developer will fix them.

Comment: Remember that this is an existing site, presumably working. Should the OP convert the whole existing site to a framework?

Comment: @Mawg  Unless the user as good as the framework with security then yes it should be converted.  Alternatively the OP could learn how to build a secure web site, but that could take months.  I have been programming in PHP for awhile without a framework.  Even I can't deny the allure of a framework.  Its like basic vs Visual Basic once you get to know it.  Even though there are no drag and drop form elements.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use wordpress or making a PHP(a language that I know) file.

Given that you would probably have to convert the entire existing site to WordPress (even  if not, you would have to learn WP and add some dependencies to your site), this seems like a no-brainer. Code some PHP. What would you gain from Press.

For the map, I highly recommend [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) wrapped around Open Street Maps. Your PHP would generate an HTML page with some very simple JS to show the map.

S.O question [Using Leaflet map in php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185748/using-leaflet-map-in-php-page)

Answer (score 0):

You could learn [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) then use [Ocsigen](https://ocsigen.org/).

Ocsigen is a dialect of Ocaml (developed in France by Vincent Belat and colleagues, used by [BeSport](https://www.about.besport.com/)) compiled into both:

- some native code running on the web server
- some Javascript running in the browser.

The typing system of Ocsigen and Ocaml ensures some kind of safety and some HTML standard conformance (of the generated HTML)

You also need to read books about HTTP. E.g. Shiflett's [*HTTP developer's handbook*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1028975.HTTP_Developer_s_Handbook).

NB. With efforts and a good design various pages of a website could be *gradually* replaced using a new framework.